# [sklearn decomposition.PCA]Which column did I deserve in my variable?

Tags: ipython, pca, decomposition

This is part of my data:

```
yahoo       msft        goog        close       open        adj
105.349998  54.799999   741.840027  105.349998  102.610001  103.057063
102.709999  55.049999   742.580017  102.709999  105.750000  100.474523
100.699997  54.049999   743.619995  100.699997  100.559998  98.508268
96.449997   52.169998   726.390015  96.449997   98.680000   94.350769
```

I converted them into the DataFrame
variable "data4" contain this part of my data.

This is my code to do the principle components analysis:

```
from sklearn import decomposition
import pandas as pd

pca1=decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)
data5=pca1.fit_transform(data4)
data5=pd.DataFrame(data5)
```

I output the data5 in ipython notebook:

```
     0          1           2
 -2.185894  -0.503732   -0.035038
 -1.986696  1.970558    0.270880
 -0.785015  7.550989    0.682496
 18.013318  7.836848    1.146809
 28.745800  2.697891    0.101636
```

This is pary of the data of the variable "data5".
I want to know the means of the  data5's columns,such as data5[0]'s original data is data4['yahoo']